# Pulling data for a check_box list from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Total Rails Noob question:

I'm having trouble getting a form to work correctly.  The application is a simple portfolio site.  You can create a project and associate tags to (e.g. on project XYZ I used skills (tags) A, B, and C).  There is a projects controller and a tags controller.   I have a project entry form that I want to pull in a list of tags the tags model.  If I pull the data in as a select box, everything is fine:

```
<%= f.label :Tag %><br />
<%= f.select :tag, Tag.all.collect { |t|
    [t.tagname] } %>
```

However, if I try to do a check box list so that you can select more than one tag per project, I get errors (an undefined method error for the code below):

```
<%= f.label :Tag %><br />
<%= f.check_box :tag, Tag.each { |t|
    [t.tagname] } %>
```

Can you advise me on what I should be doing here?  This seems like it should be pretty simple.  TIA

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this myself but thinking something like this should work

```
<% Tag.all.each do |t| %>

  <%= f.checkbox :t.tagname, t.tagname%>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :tag do |ft| %> 
   <% Tag.all.each do |t| %>
     <%= ft.check_box[] t.tagname, t.tagname %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Why don't you give try to [acts-as-taggable](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem which simple to use.